# c# - is it ok to embed a "try/catch" within a "using" statement for a web request? Is my code correct?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, try-catch, using

Is it ok to embed a "try/catch" within a "using" statement for a web request?  Is my code correct?  That is my requirements are:

1. Want to use the "using" statement to make sure resources are released in any case for HttpWebResponse

   - But still want to do some custom stuff if there is an exception re HttpWebResponse and "response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();" in particular.

My source code:

```
        var result = new HttpHeaderInfo();
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        using (response)
        {
            try
            {
                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Method = "HEAD";
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Timeout = Properties.Settings.Default.WebTimeoutDefault;

                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                result.LastModified = response.LastModified;
                result.ContentType = response.ContentType;
                result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                result.ContentLength = response.ContentLength;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is InvalidOperationException ||
                    ex is ProtocolViolationException ||
                    ex is WebException)
                {
                    result.HttpError = ex;
                    result.LastModified = System.DateTime.MinValue;
                    result.ContentType = null;
                }
                else { throw; }
            }

        }
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is OK, but a little redundant; in a general sense, you could easily remove the `using` block, add a `finally` block after the `catch`, and explicitly call `Dispose` in there, which would reduce the nesting in your code.

In a more specific sense, what bugs me a little is that you don't actually assign `response` until you get **inside** the `using` block, and the explicit variable declarations are unnecessary and confusing in this context.  I would rewrite it as:

```
HttpHeaderInfo result;
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Timeout = Properties.Settings.Default.WebTimeoutDefault;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        result = new HttpHeaderInfo();
        result.LastModified = response.LastModified;
        result.ContentType = response.ContentType;
        result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        result.ContentLength = response.ContentLength;
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // etc.
}
```

This is a lot clearer than the original form.  Also note that I'm catching `WebException`, not the generic `System.Exception`.  You should catch specific exception types instead of catching generic exceptions and then checking their type.

Comment: thanks - did you note I was effectively capturing only 3 specific exception in my code - I wasn't sure to what extend InvalidOperationException  and ProtocolViolationException cuold have been treated as system type errors (unlikely to occur unless one's code has a problem) - do you think for HTTPWebRequest here it's appropriate to only handle WebException then?

Comment: @Greg: You probably do need to handle the other exceptions, I just didn't want to clutter up the example.  To do that you can add multiple `catch` blocks - "Moron's" answer shows an example of doing that.  (Note - I would probably catch `ProtocolViolationException` but not `InvalidOperationException` - the former derives from the latter and you shouldn't get any other type of `InvalidOperationException` from `GetResponse`, not as far as I know anyway...)

Answer (score 6):

Others have pointed this out as a *potential* problem, but I want to raise it as a *very definite* problem: your using statement is doing you no good at all at the moment.

When you write a using statement like this:

```
SomeType x = value1;
using (x)
{
    x = value2;
}
```

it is `value1` which will be disposed at the end of the block, *not* `value2`. In your code, `response` is null until inside the block; the `WebResponse` you end up with will *not* be disposed.

You should be seeing a warning about this, along these lines:

> warning CS0728:
>   Possibly incorrect assignment to local
>   'response' which
>           is the argument to a using or lock statement. The Dispose call or
>           unlocking will happen on the original value of the local.

That warning is important - heed it.

Leaving that aside, it's entirely reasonable to put a try/catch block in a using statement... but in this case it should probably be *outside* the using statement, letting you initialize the `response` variable at the appropriate time so that the response will always be disposed. I would also consider using multiple catch blocks calling a common method rather than using "is" repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally OK.  You handle the exception and don't want it bubbling up further, that's just fine, and nested try/catch/finally blocks are no problem.  (Internally a 'using' like this is just a try/finally.)

UPDATE: read a little closer, and I think you actually want the using inside the 'try' block - the line where you actually put an object in the 'response' variable is where you want the 'using' block to begin.  Does it actually compile as-is?